# Ruby conditions and defined? operator weird behavior

Tags: ruby

I want to set a variable if it's not already defined, so I write

```
if defined?(var).nil?
  var = true
end
puts "[#{var}]"
```

This behaves as expected, it will print `[true]`. But if I want to simplify the snippet and write:

```
var = true if defined?(var).nil? 
puts "[#{var}]"
```

It will print `[]`.

What is the difference between these two snippets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local variable is defined from the point that the first assignment to it is parsed. Therefore, in your second snippet, the variable is defined at the point where you are calling `defined?` (since Ruby is parsed like English, i.e. left-to-right, top-to-bottom), therefore the condition is always false, therefore the assignment never gets executed, therefore, the variable never gets initialized. Un-initialized local variables evaluate to `nil` and `nil.to_s` is the empty string.

Comment: Can you explain this better? As far as I understand the `defined?` operator is the first expression that is parsed in both snippets.

Comment: Gus, no, as Jörg explains, parsing is left to right, so `var =` is the first thing parsed in #2, and that causes `var` to be initialized to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```
a #=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object)
defined?(a)
  #=> nil
a #=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object)
```

As no local variable `a` exists `defined?` returns `nil` but does not create the variable.

```
b = 1
c = defined?(b)
  #=> "local-variable"
puts "cat" if c
cat

d = nil
e = defined?(nil)
  #=> "nil"
e.nil?
  #=> false
```

`c` (`"local-variable"`) is *truthy* (logically true) because it is neither `nil` or `false` (the latter being *falsy*).

```
a #=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object)
a = true if false
  #=> nil
a #=> nil
```

This last result is an odd characteristic of Ruby. As soon as the parser sees the beginning of the assignment (`a =`) it sets `a` equal to `nil`. I understand this is done for efficiency reasons.

*Case 1*

```
d = defined?(var1)
  #=> nil 
e = d.nil?
  #=> true 
var1 = true (since e #=> true)
var1
  #=> true
```

*Case 2*

```
var2 =
  # var2 is set equal to nil
d = defined?(var2)
  #=> "nil"
e = d.nil?
  #=> false 
var2 = true if false
var2
  #=> nil
puts "[#{nil}]"
[]
```